# How can I fix this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's the error:

```
NoMethodError in Videos#feed_display

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/feed_display.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `user_id' for #<User:0x1034cb068>
```

It refers to this line:

```
<%= render_timeline current_user.recent_events %>
```

Comment: Can you put up your User model and controller? It is in one of the methods but it is impossible to say without seeing everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can recall from your last issue, I suggested interpolating `user_id`, which it seems like it needs `#{id}`?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code lurks `u.user_id` instead of `u.id`.